# SELECT c.id WHERE org_id = x AND all date columns are (NULL or < DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 2 YEAR)?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a contacts table:

```
id    org_id    date1        date2        date3 
------------------------------------------------------
1     345       22-01-2020   01-01-2019   NULL
2     567       31-01-2018   NULL         24-05-2019
```

I want to select c.id

```
where org_id = 354 AND all date columns are (NULL or < DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 2 YEAR)
```

I can't get father than this:

```
SELECT id FROM contacts
WHERE (cc.crm_organisation_id = 152 AND (cc.last_login IS NULL OR cc.last_login < DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 2 YEAR)))  
OR (cc.crm_organisation_id = 152 AND (cc.last_login_rip IS NULL OR cc.last_login_rip < DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 2 YEAR)))  
OR (cc.crm_organisation_id = 152 AND (cc.last_login_ripfa IS NULL OR cc.last_login_ripfa < DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 2 YEAR)))  
OR (cc.crm_organisation_id = 152 AND (cc.created IS NULL OR cc.created < DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 2 YEAR)))
OR (cc.crm_organisation_id = 152 AND (cc.modified IS NULL OR cc.modified < DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 2 YEAR)))
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

This is a simpler way to do it:

```
SELECT id 
FROM contacts 
WHERE org_id = 152 
AND GREATEST(
      COALESCE(date1, '1000-01-01'), 
      COALESCE(date2, '1000-01-01'), 
      COALESCE(date3, '1000-01-01')
    ) < CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 2 YEAR
```

because if the max of the 3 dates is less than 2 years ago then all dates are less than 2 years ago.

Comment: I get an error on the last line:
"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') < CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 2 YEAR' at line 1

Am I supposed to set a specific date on the COALESCE lines?

Comment: @BenjaminWhitehouse Check this: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=2cee1d40870d46774875517d4453751e there is no syntax error in my query. Do you use it correctly?

Comment: @BenjaminWhitehouse fine if it worked and don't forget to accept the answer by clicking on the checkmark.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
select id
from contacts
where crm_organisation_id = 152 and
      ( (last_login is null or last_login < curdate() - interval 2 year) or
        (last_login_ripfa is null or last_login_ripfa < curdate() - interval 2 year) or
        (created is null or created < curdate() - interval 2 year) or
        (modified is null or modified < curdate() - interval 2 year) 
      );
```